# Nonlinear recurrence relations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, recurrence-relations

There are non-linear recurrence relations of the following form:

$$ x(n+2) = \frac{x(n+1)x(n)}{x(n)-2x(n+1)}, \quad\quad
 x(0) = \frac12, x(1) = \frac13; $$
$$ x(n+2) = x(n+1)x(n)^2, \quad\quad x(0)=x(1)=2; $$

[original image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adaVu.png)

On the Internet, there is quite a bit of theory concerning the solution of this kind of relationship. Tell me, in what ways they are solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invert first equation and you get:

$${1\over x_{n+2}} = \frac{x_n-2x_{n+1}}{x_{n+1}x_n} = {1\over x_{n+1}} -{2\over x_n}$$

Now put $a_n={1\over x_n}$ then we have $a_0 =2$ and $a_1=3$ and $$a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}-2a_n$$

Now characteristic equation for this is $t^2-t+2=0$ so we have $a_n = at_1^n+bt_2 ^n$ and so on...

Comment: Thanks. And how about second? Same way?

Comment: Actualy if you log the equation you get the $b_{n+2}=b_{n+1}+2b_n$ where $b_n = \log x_n$

Answer (score 1):

For the second equation,
write
$x(n+2) = x(n+1)x(n)^2
$
as
$\ln x(n+2) = \ln x(n+1)+2\ln x(n)
$.

Now let
$y(n) = \ln x(n)$
and we get
$y(n+2) = y(n+1)+2y(n)
$.
This is a standard
linear recurrence
and can be solved
by the usual suspects.